# Creating multiple div elements using for-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I am trying to make more than one `div` using for loop, I have tried the code below but it doesn't work. I am using accordion menu, and I want to make each `div` using for loop.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<script> 
for(var i=0 ; i<3 ; i++){
<div id="accordion" style="width:50%">

  <h3>Section i</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
}
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you MAY use a template or THINK you are - perhaps wishful thinking? You likely need to look at clone

Comment: What is that "for" function? HTML don't have function.

Comment: why don't you create HTML dynamically  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never do like this, best practice is to use template engines or some server-side languages for this. But anyway, this solution in JS will probably work for you.

```
<div id="accordion" style="width:50%"></div>
<script>
var html = '';
var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ..';
// first we generating our html in the loop
for(var i=0 ; i<3 ; i++) {
  html += '<div><h3>Section ' + i + '</h3>';
  html += '<p>' + text + '</p></div>';
}
// next we're inserting html into block with ID accordion
document.getElementById("accordion").innerHTML = html;
</script>
```

Comment: your answer helped me a lot, but when i copied your code, it wasn't what i want exactly.
I modified it and it worked.
 `<div id="accordion" style="width:50%"></div>
<script>
var html = '';
var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ..';
for(var i=0 ; i<6 ; i++) {
  html += '<h3>Section ' + i + '</h3>' + '<div><p>' + text + '</p></div>';
}
document.getElementById("accordion").innerHTML = html;
</script>` 
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is pretty straightforward in this way (I mean generating HTML at interpret-time dynamically).

Afterwards you can also have another button to transform them into an accordion.

```js
$('#foo').click(generate);

function generate() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
    $('<div></div>')
      .text('Div no ' + i)
      .addClass('some-class')
      .appendTo('#container');
  }
}
```

```css
.some-class{
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid greenyellow;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 2px;
  font-family: Calibri;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="foo">Generate HTML</button>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that repeat function in HTML. You either use language like php or copy-paste duplicate your HTML. In that case you can't duplicate ID. So you better use class.

```
<div class="accordion" style="width:50%">

  <h3>Section i</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="accordion" style="width:50%">

  <h3>Section i</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="accordion" style="width:50%">

  <h3>Section i</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

And javascript is:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".accordion" ).accordion();
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: OP would like to generate HTML *dynamically* by JavaScript, which your answer does not address.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you will use it but in JavaScript you can do like this:since you are going to repeat the same data use class instead.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
      str="";
      for(var i=0 ; i<3 ; i++){
      str=str+'<div class="accordion" style="width:50%"> <h3>Section i</h3> <div> <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integerut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit</p> </div></div>';
      }
      $('body').html(str);
    $( ".accordion" ).accordion();
  });
  </script>
</head><body> 
</body>
</html>
```